# Mongodb aggregation: $reduce not working as expected

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, reduce

I have a mongodb aggregation `$reduce` pipleine that is not working as expected. [This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZNJbTXj2YcA) is what I am trying to achieve.

Basically I am trying to get the object with the highest value in a given property. In some objects `$reduce` returns the wrong object in others it returns `null`, meaning no object satisfied the condition.

My code has the group stage and other stage that produce the variable used in the `$reduce` stage. Are there any known preceding stages in the aggregation pipeline that might be affecting the `$reduce` stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$max` to get max value from `key` array of field `a`, this will return `-15` as per your documents
- `$filter` to get object that equal to `-15` value
- `$first` get first object from returned result from `$filter`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      winner: {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$key",
            cond: { $eq: ["$$this.a", { $max: "$key.a" }] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZzsZ28Ha_bx)

---

Second option using `$reduce` operator,

- set initial field `maxValue` in reduce, maximum value from `key` array of field `a`
- check condition if `maxValue` and `a` value match then return max object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      winner: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$key",
          initialValue: { maxValue: { $max: "$key.a" } },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.a", "$$value.maxValue"] },
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FTUYme-hy7P)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue I was facing with `$reduce` is it caused other preceding aggregations or is my code working as expected?

Comment: You don't need to use `$reduce` in that approach look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rwRPWk0BAVi), you can just use $last operator