# MongoDB aggregation: How to get an object in an array that has the highest value and also satisfies another condition without using $reduce?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

This question is a continuation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65039580/9953550).

Let's say I have this data

```
[
    {id:0, points:-9, rank:true}
    {id:1, points:-49, rank:true}
    {id:2, points:9, rank:false}
    {id:3, points:-24, rank:false}
    {id:4, points:3, rank:true}
]
```

I want to get the object with the highest points and rank is equal to positive and add the property `winner:true` So in this case the object with `id:4`. How can I achieve the same in MongoDB aggregation without using `$reduce`?

Comment: If no positive points are available just use negative points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

- `$match` `rank` is positive
- `$sort` by `points` ascending order
- `$group` by null and get last object from group document
- `$replaceRoot` to replace `winner` object to root
- `$addFields` to add new field `winner: true`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { rank: true } },
  { $sort: { points: 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      winner: { $last: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$winner" } },
  { $addFields: { winner: true } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y_GF7caElqR)

Comment: Thank you. From your answer I have actually seen my solution. I will `$map` to get an array with only objects where `rank == true`. Then I can now use `$reduce`